# Custom NSDateFormatter.timeZone - Swift

Tags: swift, timezone, nsdateformatter

Im currently creating timezones with the following format:

```
    let ukTz = NSDateFormatter();
    ukTz.dateFormat = "HH:mm";
    ukTz.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "Europe/London")
```

I'd like to make a similar variable in my code, but for Myanmar (UTC +6:30). Myanmar seems to be the only country in this timezone, and there is no `NSTimeZone(name: "Asia/Yangon")`. Is there a way i can do this by specifying "UTC+6.30"?

Comment: When in doubt,check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a time zone with a given GMT offset:

```
let tz = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT+0630") // or
let tz = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC+0630") // or
let tz = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 6 * 3600 + 30 * 60)
```

But what you are probably looking for is

```
let tz = NSTimeZone(name: "Asia/Rangoon")
```

(using the english name for Yangon).

Comment: I always thought it was Yangon.. Cheers!

Comment: +1.  FYI - Though Mynamar is now fixed at UTC+06:30, There were [a few years during WW2 where Myanmar was on UTC+09:00](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/myanmar/yangon?syear=1940&eyear=1949), which will only be reflected when using `Asia/Rangoon`.  The same applies if they ever switch offsets in the future, or decide to implement DST.  Other countries have done just that, many times around the world.  Therefore it's always best to use location-based identifiers.